# LI elements go out of order when changing screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in which I give several links using a styled UL. When the resolution is set to 100% it looks great, but when I change the screen resolution the links do not fit into the menu and some of them go to another line which causes annoying bugs.

My question is; how is it possible? I mean, if all the elements sit together when the resolution is set to 100%, when I change the resolution all elements should scale accordingly, meaning the menu structure is not supposed to change. 
What is the best way of making this menu static and preventing the reorder of the LI?

My code:

```
<ul class="top-menu drop" style="margin:4px 10px 0 0;">
//get items from DB to var $Result
while($a_row=mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{
 $menu_id++;
 echo "<li><a href=''>$a_row[main_product_name]</a>";
 echo "<ul class='drop-down' id='menu$menu_id'>";
 //populate the menu UL
 echo "</ul></li>";
}
```

The css for the menu:

```
.top-menu{
padding:0;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
height:20px;
list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Anton, You need some more information if you want a helpful answer. Your issues is not with the style of .top-menu but with the style of what it contains (probably `.top-menu li` and `.top-menu .drop-down` or something similar. Update your question with that code and the HTML your code generates (copy it from the browsers view-source is probably the easiest) and it will be easier to answer. You may also want to include the HTML+CSS for the element that contains your menu.

Comment: @AdamvandenHoven hi man, the drop downs and LI are irrelevant since they open only when i hover over the UL. i want the UL to sit nicely and i dont care about the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways:

1) Pure css solution make the width of the list elements with percents (making them fluid). But you may want to have diferent widths and making each one with different width will be to much work, so you can use the second option then.

2) Javascript: Check the position of the last element, and if it falls down you can decrease the padding or the font-size untill they fit on one row.

Comment: hi and thank you for your answer, i do have different lengths in my menu. so i think the second is more relevant. how would you know if an element went out of the div containing him to a new row?

Comment: You can take the first element offset().top and the last element offset().top if they are differet, then the last element is on the second row, so you decrease what you want untill those two are equal to each other. You make this in a function and do it for window load and window resize

Comment: the thing is i load the menu items with PHP this means after the page loades doesnt it? will it couse a problem?

Comment: There will be no problem.

Comment: for some reason it always shows that the offset is 0. should all the elements be position:realtive or something like that?

Comment: Mmm check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yBPcZ/1/ I just leave you the logic for when you need to increase the window size. :) (since now it will stay that way)

Answer (score 0):

it is because of your margin right `margin:0 10px 0 0;`.css only solution  will be `media query`

like

```
.style{
 margin-righ:10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
 .style{
 margin-righ:4px;
 }
}
```

**[learn more about media query here(w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)**